# broken "updateUrl" when sharing on a company page

Tags: linkedin-api

Whenever I share on a company page, the "updateUrl" that is returned leads to a 404 page.

[image]

```
https://www.linkedin.com/company/{company_id}/comments?topic={topic_id}&type=U&scope={scope_id}&stype=C&a=yzVb
```

This happens every single time. Before this started happening, there would be a "small" delay between the post and the URL "becoming" valid, now it just stays invalid forever.

It's just unacceptable, first you no longer allow OAuth 1 tokens when posting to company pages without any prior notice and I still haven't seen any "updates" in the documentation or elsewhere regarding this matter, AND NOW you also break the "URLs", yet again without any official announcements.

Since there is no "Linkedin Status Page" we don't even know if this is a "known" issue that is being actively worked on, or if it has been reported before at all.

Just to be perfectly clear, this is not a "code" issue on my end, the same thing happens when I "create" the share using the "REST Console" over https://apigee.com/console/linkedin .

Answer (score 3):

Since it looks like this is not going to get fixed anytime soon, even though I've been told that they are aware of the issue, in the meantime I ended up "constructing" the "permalink" to the "update" myself by using the "updateKey":

```
id = "UPDATE-c5323310-6328147480441683969"
url = "https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:#{id.split('-').last}/"
```

It's not ideal and very error prone, since they could change the permalinks again, but at least it works for now as a "temporary" workaround.