# Linkedin API Company share updateUrl returns invalid link

Tags: linkedin-api

When creating a post via API, Linkedin is returning a invalid page as the post URL,

Request URL: https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/2414183/shares?format=json

Return Example:
"updateUrl": "https://www.linkedin.com/company/2414183/comments?topic=6329365970687131648&type=U&scope=2414183&stype=C&a=kQPg"

How can i get the real post address?

Comment: Are you using v1 OAuth 1.0a  or v2 OAuth 2.0 authentication token ? Did you activate shares option when you've created the application?

Comment: We have migrated from Auth1 to Auth2 recently and the share option is activated, the company share is created successfully, the problema is the link to the created post that returns an invalid page

Comment: so you link isn't good look at the version you use :  https://api.linkedin.com/v1/   you use version 1 and you want v2 ... etc

Comment: is there a v2 for the api?

Comment: yes https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/people/primary-contact-api

Comment: @headmax stop spreading FUD, there is no v2 API, and even if it was, OAuth 2 has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @c0d3rguy i am no spreading FUD i read the documentation, i am no a linkedin https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2 `Alert: Starting 10 October 2017 developers must use TLS 1.1 or 1.2 when calling LinkedIn APIs. LinkedIn no longer supports TLS 1.0 for security reasons.` https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/concepts/authentication#auth i guess you need to read or the linkedin site are joking with RTFM;

Comment: And yet again you are spreading idiotic FUD, TLS has nothing to do with OAuth or the API. Just leave and get your reputation points elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reported the same issue [days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46845775/broken-updateurl-when-sharing-on-a-company-page) and they still didn't address it, even though they said over Twitter that their engineering team is aware of the issue and working on a fix.

Haven't heard from them since then.

I just ended up constructing the "right" permalink "by hand":

```
id = "UPDATE-c5323310-6328147480441683969"
url = "https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:#{id.split('-').last}/"
```

Comment: Thanks you saved me hours of hair pulling. Still not solved even in 2018. That is just sad.